# Calculating a total frame loss in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, frames, requestanimationframe

I have an HTML5 Canvas application, animated using requestanimationframe.

I have a counter variable which counts the number of frames shown. From what I've observed, requestanimationframe is limited to 60fps (at least in Chrome and Opera).

Firstly, is it true that requestanimationframe is limited to 60fps?

And secondly, how would I calculate how many frames are being lost inside a variable? For example, if the fps drops below 60 for 1 second, add the difference to 60 fps in a second variable, so as to eventually calculate the maximum possible number of frames that would be shown in a period of n seconds.

Answer (score 1):

**Why 60fps?**

The w3c recommends that requestAnimationFrame (RAF) fires at the same interval as the browser refreshes.  This synchronization between the RAF drawings and the display hardware reduces the likelihood of "tearing" (displaying an incomplete draw).

So most browsers attempt to fire the RAF callback 60 times per second to match most display refresh rates.

**Adjusting for 'dropped frames'**

RAF may 'drop' a frame for a number of reasons including system activities like garbage collection or drawings that take longer the accomplish than 1/60th second.

The recent version of RAF sends a timestamp into its callback function.

```
function animate(timestamp){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

This timestamp lets you draw based on an elapsed time rather than simply a count of times the loop has executed.

For example, if you are animating an object across the canvas at 1 pixel per frame then ideally the object would move 60 pixels in 1 second.

If any frame is dropped you can use the timestamp to determine where the object should be drawn based on time rather than based on the number of times the loop has executed.

```
var lastTime;

function animate(timestamp){

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    if(!lastTime){lastTime=timestamp;}

    var elapsed=timestamp-lastTime;

    // draw based on elapsed time rather than 
    // based on # times animate() has executed

}
```

So in the example, if frame 10 is dropped then the next frame can use the timestamp to draw the object +11 pixels based on time (even though the loop has executed only 10 times).